# Responsive table alignment of columns

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-tables

In responsive table design to refer I got this link jsfiddle.net/n4rUG/27/

This gives me below output:

[image]

Now I want to align title to left and its value to right 
means it need to look aligned properly

How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text-align: right` doesn't work for your `td`s because it's overridden by the Bootstrap style with higher specifity. The quickest solution is just to add `!important`. Also, I'd suggest to make the labels floating to left (see [modified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4rUG/28/)):

```
    td {
        ...
        text-align: right !important;
        overflow: hidden; /* for containg floats */
    }
    td:before {
        ...
        float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSFiddle is different then the image in your post.

Refering to your image, you could make it like this, using colspan to set your colums width:

```
<table>
   <colgroup>
      <col width="100px" />
      <col width="200px" />
   </colgroup>
   <tr>
      <td>title</td>
      <td>value</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>title</td>
      <td>value</td>
   </tr>
...
</table>
```

As for your JSFiddle, you have 5 `<th>`'s and 6 `<td>`'s. Which is possible, however, one of the `<th>` should cover two `<td>`'s, you can make that by using this:

```
<th colspan="2">Title</th>
```